# Is there a way to restrict params to certain values while using react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a site with react and react-router and I have two different type of routes, like in the example bellow:

```js
<Route name="products" path="/:type/*" handler={ ProductList } />
<Route name="generic-template" path="/*" handler={ TemplatePage } />
```

So my products page needs the type parameter, which can be A, B or C and I want any link that I access to match my products route only if the type is A, B or C. So as an example:

- /type-A/bla-bla-filter -> ProductList should load
- /type-B/other-params -> ProductList should load
- /services/details -> TemplatePage should load

But with what I have now, any page is matched by the Products route because the type is simply matched as the first string after the slash. As a workaround, I tried to wrap my ProductList component into separate wrapper components that just send that type parameter along like this:

```js
var TypeAWrapper = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <ProductList params={{ splat: this.props.params.splat, type: 'A' }} />
    );
  }
});

var TypeBWrapper = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <ProductList params={{ splat: this.props.params.splat, type: 'B' }} />
    );
  }
});
```

and then I used a different route for each type of product with static matching.

Does anyone know a better solution for this?

Answer (score 25):

extracted from [official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

```
   {/* It's possible to use regular expressions to control what param values should be matched.
     * "/order/asc"  - matched
     * "/order/desc" - matched
     * "/order/foo"  - not matched*/}
   <Route
     path="/order/:direction(asc|desc)"
     component={ComponentWithRegex}
   />
```

You could mix regular expressions with the exact props of the Route component to avoid that product is always matched

Comment: not working this way

Comment: @GeorgeGuo this worked 3 and a half year ago, in React Router 3.. you are most likely using an updated version and this may no longer work

Comment: right, not work anymore, any new solution to this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution from here: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9844#discussioncomment-4692242

It's for **React Router v6**

The function **LangParamValidator** is example. You can use this approach to implement your validation.

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path=":lang" element={<LangParamValidator />}>
    <Route index element={<RouteWithLangParam />} />
  <Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>

function LangParamValidator() {
  const { lang } = useParams<'lang'>()

  if (lang && ALLOWED_LANGS.incldues(lang)) {
    return <Outlet />
  }

  return <Navigate path="/" replace />
}
```