# How to restrict url params to a certain set of values using react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router v6 to define routes like this.

```
<Routes>  
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
  <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
  <Route path="/shop">
    <Route index element={<ShopPage />} />
    <Route path=":category" element={<CategoryPage />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Here's the ShopPage code to navigate to "/shop/:category"

```
const categories = ['shoes', 'jeans', 'sweaters']; // originally populated using an api 
{categories.map(category => <Link to=`/shop/${category}`>${category}</Link>}
```

I want to restrict navigating to CategoryPage only when the category param has a value from the above defined set.
What I'm doing currently is conditionally rendering stuff on CategoryPage depending on category param received.

For example, if user navigates to "/shop/xyz", I just show a 'not found' error & a link to go back to shop. What I would like though is to somehow pre-check destination path and to not move to CategoryPage at all in this case.

I tried to do something like

```
 <Route path=":category('shoes'|'jeans'|'sweaters')" element={<CategoryPage />} />
```

as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54113392/6661730/) but that just redirects me to root path '/' for all param values.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions were removed from route paths in `react-router-dom@6`. See  ["What Happened to Regexp Routes Paths?"](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths) for details.

You've a couple options:

1. Explicitly render the routes you want to match. For this you map the categories in the same way as you did the links.

   ```
   <Routes>  
     <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
     <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
     <Route path="/shop">
       <Route index element={<ShopPage />} />
       {categories.map(category => (
         <Route
           key={category}
           path={category} // <-- "/shop/shoes", "/shop/jeans", "/shop/sweaters"
           element={<CategoryPage />}
         />
       ))}
     </Route>
   </Routes>
   ```
2. Validate the `category` route path parameter in a matched component. I'd suggest creating a category wrapper component that reads and validates the `category` path parameter and bounces a user off the route if the category isn't valid.

   ```
   import { Navigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

   const CategoryWrapper = ({ categories = [], children }) => {
     const { category } = useParams();

     const isValid = !categories.length || categories.includes(category);

     return isValid ? children : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
   };
   ```

   ```
   <Routes>  
     <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
     <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
     <Route path="/shop">
       <Route index element={<ShopPage />} />
       <Route
         path=":category"
         element={(
           <CategoryWrapper categories={categories}>
             <CategoryPage />
           <CategoryWrapper>
         )}
       />
     </Route>
   </Routes>
   ```