# how to define route restriction in remix

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

in react router
I can define my route restriction like:

```
<Route
  path={'/f/:sub(a|b|c)'}
  component={Layout}                
/>
```

so that the route only be in three way:  /f/a, /f/b, /f/c

But
how could I do this in Remix ?
I know I need to create a file:  f.$sub.tsx
but how should I do the restriction to my route ? (a|b|c)

I had done this
but not work:
f.$sub(a|b|c).tsx

and maybe I can do f.a.tsx, f.b.tsx, f.c.tsx
but I think it's a little dumb....?

Comment: Do you need the `sub` route path parameter in the `Layout` component? Or do you just need to restrict what is matched? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74603651/8690857

Answer (score 0):

Currently React Router 6+, and thus Remix, do not support regex path patterns, unlike previous versions of RR.

It only matches on complete segments. So you'll need to do something like `routes/f.$sub.tsx`, and in your loader, check if `params.sub` matches the pattern and throw 404 if not.

```
// routes/f.$sub.tsx
export async function loader({ request, params }) {
  let match = /^(.+)(a|b|c)$/g.exec(params.sub)
  if (!match) throw new Response('Not Found', 404)
  let sub = match[1]

  //...
}
```